# Python objects circular references (through attributes) and testing for equality

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, testing, circular-reference

I have been trying to find the answer to this question for a while now and while I am finding a lot of information on circular references and testing objects for equality, I cannot seem to find the exact answer I am looking for.

For clarity, I am working in Python 3.6.8.

Now I have different objects that I would like to create links between. They are not parents or children of each other, so I do not want to use inheritance, but I would like to link these objects through attributes. I would like to be able to have this link both ways, so I can reach the other object from either of the objects. This results into something like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class B():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

Thus, from an instance of class A I am able to direct which instance of class B it relates to and the other way around.

However, I believe this creates some type of circular reference.

In addition, I can run into some problems when testing around these classes (unittest, pytest, etc.). In my test, I would have an object of class B which I would like to compare to the object of class B which my code returns. However, I run into recursion errors when I try to compare these objects.

In summary, the questions I have are:

- Is this type of "circular reference" a problem? Is it something I should avoid? If yes, what "better" (more pythonic) ways would there be to ensure I can still link between these objects??
- Either using the type of linking I described or another proposed method, what would be the best way in which I can test if different objects are equal? Note I do not want to see if the object ID's are equal, just if the content of the objects are equal.

Thanks in advance for everyone's time.

Comment: One interesting test would be to put prints in `__del__()` and see if it gets called and in which order?

Comment: How would you define "similarity" between two objects that have other linked objects inside? If you're defining it as "the objects have the same content", then you're going to have to define it as a set of "how many levels deep" - especially if you don't want to consider the ids to see if it's the same object further down the stack

Comment: @MatsLindh the similarity would indeed be about having the same content. Describing the amount of levels could be an option but ideally I think it should keep comparing until it meets an object that it has already come across.

Comment: I guess my question is also just a bit more generic, not even depending on my scenario specifically.

- How do people go about linking between objects when they want to be able to toggle back and forth both ways?
- Is the circular referencing between objects this way a problem? How would you solve that?
- How do people create tests when the output includes objects? How do you compare them?

Comment: It's not usually an issue - you'd keep track of objects you've visited when serializing/iterating through it. You've effectively described an [Doubly Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). You'll have to be careful about describing the properties of that list - i.e. what identical would mean (for example, iterating through the list would give the same sequence of values). When it comes down to object similarity, it's up to you to decide what identical means, usually by implementing `__eq__` or checking each property explicitly in your test.